# Theoretical solution about implementing foreign key related data

Tags: mysql, database

How would you implement the following?

I would like to insert data to mysql tables. Let's imagine there are two tables where a foreign key relation exists. First, i insert a row that has a primary key that should be inserted as a foreign key to one of the rows to the other table. So when i would like to insert the foreign key and it's related data, i have to know the primary key of the related row in the other table. As i am a beginner, my solution would be the following: I would insert a field value with a particular data to the original table so that the inserted value could be used to retrieve the primary key with a SELECT, and then insert the retrieved primary key as the foreign key to the related rows of the other table.

Although I don't know a better solution, I think this would be a very clumsy way to implement this logic. There must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: How exactly are you planning to insert the values? Manually? Scriptomatically? Using a Web Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution won't work because if you are inserting not unique data, you may not retrieve the appropriate primary key. MySQL offers `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function for this. Just insert row into your primary key table and then use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. It returns last primary key value inserted into your original table (last insert query) and now you can use it as foreign key in related table.

Comment: Thank you,it's definitely better!